# C# socket StreamReader.ReadToEnd wait forever

Tags: c#, uwp, streamreader

In an Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app, I'm trying to send an object to a Windows form program using socket:

```
public void CreateListener()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            if (listener.Pending())
            {
                var childSocketThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    string data = null;
                    var Client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    using (NetworkStream ns = Client.GetStream())
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns))
                    {
                        data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Orders>(data);
                        Process(Items);
                        ns.Flush();
                        ns.Close();
                    }
                });
                childSocketThread.IsBackground = true;
                childSocketThread.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50); //<--- timeout
            }
        }
    }
```

But receiving object stuck in `ReadToEnd` and never exit.
What should I do?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216943/tcpclient-stream-streamreader-readtoend-for-telnet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216943/tcpclient-stream-streamreader-readtoend-for-telnet)

Comment: `sr.ReadToEnd()` will wait as long as the `Stream` is closed. Thus, as long as the `Stream` is not closed, it will stuck forever. Check out the post referred by @spaceplane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have problem when you want to send data, after flushing your StreamWriter object you have to use StreamReader as a response.

```
            Stream streamIn = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
            string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
```

Hope this would help you.